# Xcode project linked through git builds on one computer but receives error on other

Tags: ios, xcode, git

(The two computers are the same MacBook version)

Though our project builds on one computer, we are receiving the following error message on the other:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>         Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you >don't want. 
>         Try this:
>
> ```
>       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't >expect; 
>
>       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints >and fix it.
> ```

**$git status** tells us we are up to date

The only thing we came up with was that we have different Xcode versions (which we will update soon), but seeing as it is 8.3.3 vs 8.3.2 we doubt that is the cause of the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could this be a library version or dependency difference problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? How would we fix that?

Comment: Check your dependencies on both machines.  If you don't know what I'm talking about then research it.

Comment: That looks like a runtime error, so are you running it on the same target device in the same orientation with the same test data and the same localization?